# Why does text not stay the same size when I zoom in my browser?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am making a website and trying to make it scale well, but the text isn't staying the same size.

Ex:

```css
p {
  width: 10%;
  height: 10%;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  color: rgb(255,255,255);
  font-size: 175%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCType html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>:(</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div><p>TEXT</p></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is just an example. Not exactly how I am doing it. The div will same relatively the same size when you zoom in or out your browser, but the text doesn't seem to stay in the box.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Previous answer: Try to use em instead of percentage.

If you want it to scale well you need to have a relative measurement for your css. em and percentage can help you there.

If you want the text to stay the same size despite the browser being zoomed in/out you can achieve this using viewport:

https://css-tricks.com/examples/ViewportTypography/

```
p {
  font-size: 2vmin;
}
```

However this isn't recommended and the format vh, vw, and vmin have compabitilies issues.

Comment: It does not help

Comment: Do you think it is a bad idea to use vh, vw, etc.?

Comment: @BOBONA This isn't a fail-proof solution because if the user has changed his zoom settings to text-only your page wouldn't respond how you expect it to.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to make use of text-size-adjust property but it only works in latest versions of chrome and edge with support of prefix:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-size-adjust

Answer (score 0):

I decided I will specify everything in pixels and set overflow to scroll. That way no matter who views it, they will see the exact same page. They just might have to scroll to see it all.
Once more browsers are up to date with all these new text attributes this might not be practical.